# Question about the Eberlein-Smulian theorem's proof

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

In the article **An elementary proof of the Eberlein-Smulian Theorem** by Robert Whitley on the Math. Annalen 192 they say this:
[image: Eberlein-Smulian proof]

but it is supposed that $w^*(JA)\subset X''$ and the weak$^*$ topology is over $X'$ so it does not have sense to call it compact on the weak$^*$ topology.

Comment: They mean the weak$^*$ topology on  $X’’$ as the dual space of $X’$.